# Problem with a circuit of an controlled variable voltage source

Tags: led, capacitor, resistors, diodes, source

[image: Circuit]

I have this circuit, it should regulate the output voltage between 15V and 0V. But the output I get when I simulate it is between 2V and 3V, and when I implemented, I burned zener diode 1N4734A. Anyone know the problem?

Some components:

- 4 transistors NPN BC548
- 1 potentiometer (linear) 10[K ohm]

The input voltage is 220V/50Hz and the transformer goes from 220V to 15V.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I can't for the life of me figure out hoe your circuit is supposed to work. Can you give any sort of description. It seems to me that the value of R2 is way to high & surely the R8/9/10 voltage divider should actually be connected to the output somehow to give a feedback voltage to Q2? Shouldn't the top end of R5/Q1 be connected to the supply voltage input? Just some guesses ...

Comment: @brhans they were connected, i uploaded an old pic, sorry. i edited the post with all the information i know about it.

Answer (score 1):

The simulation doesn't work because you have no connection between R5 and the unregulated voltage, nor between R8 and the output voltage. In fact, you simply seem to have these two nodes connected directly together for some reason.

I can't say why your zener diode burned up, but what you wired probably doesn't match this schematic exactly.

Comment: this is the original circuit with the original values​​, the above was a mistake. after implementing it for the second time the transistor Q5 burned

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand some of that.  (What's going on around Z2?)  And why is R5 biased from the output... that will be a problem if you ever get it working.  (The voltage divider off the out put looks a bit out off.. 47k, 5 k pot 47k.. not much of a range..)  I'd suggest building the circuit up a piece at a time, making sure you understand what each piece does.  Q5 looks to be a current limiter, but it's hard to tell for sure.  Did you copy this from somewhere?  A link to the original circuit may help.

Comment: My teacher gave me this circuit, he says it worked several years ago but I'm not sure. I've looked all over the internet but I can't find any circuit like this

Comment: Ah, well then by all means ask your teacher to explain it.  The various circuit pieces are all very common.  Q1/Q2 is a differential amp. (though a weirdly biased Q1)  and Q3/Q4 a Darlington output.  Your job is to understand what each does and hook them up correctly.